# Transfer of Certificates

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4.3

I recently bought a new macbook pro and downloaded Xcode. I tried downloading my developer certificates from developer.apple/membercenter but it gives me the message no private keys available. How do I get my provisioning profiles and certificate on my new laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the keys from your original computer's keychain. Go to the keychain app, find your certificate, select the private keys and export them. You need these keys on your new computer.